# Mysql Function error

Tags: function, cursor

I am new to MySql...
I was trying to write a function that would calculate the total punch time of any driver .
I have driver_id, login_datetime , login_status(0/1) in my table.
If login_status is 1 , the login_datetime is as login time and if status is 0 then its logout time.

I want to pass driver id and want to get his total working time ....
But through this code it returns no rows fetched or retrieved..
Please help out in this matter...

My piece of code is as following

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `time_calc`;

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `time_calc`(driver integer)
 RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN

DECLARE a BIGINT(255);
DECLARE b int(11);
DECLARE c INT(25);
DECLARE d TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE e TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE f TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE g VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE log_time TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE out_time TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE tot_time DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pre_time DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
declare login_stat VARCHAR(1);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM clg where driver_id=driver;

OPEN cur1;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a,b,c,d,e,f,g;

    if g=1 THEN
            SET log_time=f;
ELSEIF g=0 THEN
            SET out_time=f;
        SET  pre_time= TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(out_time,log_time))/3600;
        end if;
        SET tot_time=tot_time+pre_time;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;




    RETURN tot_time;
END;
```

Comment: Are you sure you tried to run this in your sql instance? I could see few syntax errors.

Comment: I used navicat to create it and was executing through it and didn'1 find any syntax error... Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Sorry for confusion. While I was viewing the question I found incomplete `where`c clause but its fixed now. Actually you are reading from cursor and calculating `tot_time` but you dont have any terminating condition.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

Comment: I didn't got your point about terminating condition. i have closed the cursor after end of loop, is there any other thing to be defined for terminating conditions

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html